# SQL Server datetime2 field is missing AM/PM

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL table I have a field of type `datetime2`. I just noticed that it stores data in a 12-hour format without AM/PM specified.

For example from yesterday night records have

> 2016-10-24 08:08:46

and it is not clear whether it is AM or PM hours. Can someone tell me what is going on and how can I fix it? Is that something with `datetime2` format?

Comment: That's probably displayed in 24 hour format

Comment: `12-hour format without AM/PM specified`, you mean in a 24 hour format. Anyway, datetime doesn't store the data formatted, it's just a number that's **displayed** in a particular format

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought about that but I do know the record had been inserted at 8:08PM. Basically at this point there are only PM records in the database so there cannot be any mistake

Comment: @Lamak, unfortunately no, it does not display 24-hour format as that `8:08` shoule really have been `16:08`

Comment: How it was stored is different than how is being displayed. How exactly is the data being inserted into the table?, how is it being retrieved now?

Comment: The value is shown from select query? Or when u open the table?

Comment: Actually 8:08PM is 20:08 in 24hr format.

Comment: As @Lamak already mentioned the database stores datetime as a number. If you have wrong values than check the code that inserts the datetime values your problem will be there

Comment: Check the SQL client you are using maybe you can configure it to display the value as 12hr format

Comment: basically #BlameDevs... unless it was you that wrote the insert code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source system is providing you values in an incorrect format that you are not handling properly before they are inserted into your database.  This is not a limitation or failing of the `datetime2` datatype, but of your data import process.